# TextView not showing String variable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

My TextView isn't showing the string that i set it. The normal setText method with the .getText parameters works perfectly fine, but the part where i interact with the WorkWithChem class doesn't.

For example, if i enter in H2O as my compound and enter in 5 moles, the textview for moles will show 5, but the grams textview changes from  to just what appears to be an empty string.

My guess is that it has something to do with the if statements in the onClick method, the xml files, or the WorkWithChem class.

This is what I've got.

Sorry in advance for the sloppy code, I'm relatively new at this (More so android development than java)

AndroidManifest xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.justin.firstapp">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo">
        android:label="@String/ActivityTwo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Activity java file

```
package com.example.justin.firstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textViewGrams, textViewMoles;
EditText editTextCompound, editTextGrams, editTextMoles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_two);

    textViewGrams = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGrams);
    textViewMoles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMoles);
    editTextCompound = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editComp);
    editTextGrams = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editGrams);
    editTextMoles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMoles);
    Button buttonCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);

    buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!editTextCompound.getText().equals(null)) {

                ArrayList<Elements> comp = new WorkWithChem().compound(editTextCompound.getText().toString());


                if (!editTextGrams.getText().equals(null) &&
                        !editTextMoles.getText().equals(null)) {

                    textViewMoles.setText(editTextMoles.getText());
                    textViewGrams.setText(editTextGrams.getText());

                } else if (!editTextMoles.getText().equals(null)) {

                    textViewMoles.setText(editTextMoles.getText());

                    textViewGrams.setText(WorkWithChem.getGrams(comp, new BigDecimal(WorkWithChem.stringToNumber(editTextGrams.getText().toString()).doubleValue())).toString());


                } else if (!editTextGrams.getText().equals(null)) {

                    textViewGrams.setText(editTextGrams.getText());

                    textViewMoles.setText(WorkWithChem.getMoles(comp, new BigDecimal(WorkWithChem.stringToNumber(editTextMoles.getText().toString()).doubleValue())).toString());

                }

            }


        }
    });
}



}
```

Activity xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.justin.firstapp.ActivityTwo">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@android:string/untitled"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMoles"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewGrams"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Total moles"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewMoles"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@android:string/untitled"
    android:id="@+id/textViewGrams"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewMoles"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Total grams"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editComp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Enter a compound"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewMoles"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editGrams"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editComp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Enter grams" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editMoles"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editComp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editComp"
    android:hint="Enter moles" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editGrams"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="thing"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

WorkWithChem class

```
package com.example.justin.firstapp;

import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WorkWithChem{

public static boolean isCapitol(char c){
    if(c == 'A' || c == 'B' || c == 'C' || c == 'D' || c == 'E' || c == 'F' || c == 'G' || c == 'H' || c == 'I' || c == 'J' || c == 'K' || c == 'L' || c == 'M' || c == 'N' || c == 'O' || c == 'P' || c == 'Q' || c == 'R' || c == 'S' || c == 'T' || c == 'U' || c == 'V' || c == 'W' || c == 'X' || c == 'Y' || c == 'Z')
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static ArrayList<Elements> compound (String str){

    ArrayList<Elements> elements = new ArrayList();

    String temp = str.toString();

    for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++){

        if(isCapitol(str.charAt(i))){

            if(containsDigit(str)){

                for(int addCounter = Integer.parseInt(extractNumber(str)); addCounter > 0; addCounter--){

                    elements.add(Elements.getBySymbol(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(extractNumber(str)))));
                }

            }else{

                elements.add(Elements.getBySymbol(str.substring(0, i)));
            }

            temp = temp.substring(i);
        }
    }

    elements.add(Elements.getBySymbol(temp));

    return elements;
}

public static BigDecimal getGrams(BigDecimal moles, BigDecimal molarMass){

    return moles.multiply(molarMass);
}

public static BigDecimal getGrams(ArrayList<Elements> compound, BigDecimal moles){
    BigDecimal ans = new BigDecimal(0);

    for(Elements e : compound){

        BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(e.getAtomicMass().doubleValue());

        ans.equals(ans.add(temp.multiply(moles)));
    }

    return ans;

}

public static BigDecimal getMolarMass(ArrayList<Elements> compound){
    BigDecimal ans = new BigDecimal(0);

    for(Elements e : compound){
        ans.equals(ans.add(e.getAtomicMass()));
    }

    return ans;

}

public static final boolean containsDigit(String s) {
    boolean containsDigit = false;

    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (containsDigit = Character.isDigit(c)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return containsDigit;
}

public static BigDecimal stringToNumber(String str){
    String s = extractNumber(str);

    return new BigDecimal(str);

}

public static String extractNumber(String str) {

    if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
        return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean found = false;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.'){
            sb.append(c);
            found = true;
        } else if(found){
            // If we already found a digit before and this char is not a digit, stop looping
            break;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public static BigDecimal getMoles(BigDecimal grams, BigDecimal molarMass){

    return grams.multiply(molarMass);
}

public static BigDecimal getMoles(ArrayList<Elements> compound, BigDecimal molarMass){
    BigDecimal ans = new BigDecimal(0);

    for(Elements e : compound){

        BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(e.getAtomicMass().doubleValue());

        ans.equals(ans.add(temp.multiply(molarMass)));
    }

    return ans;

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Elements> list = compound("O");

    BigDecimal mass = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal moles = new BigDecimal(2);



    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        mass = mass.add(list.get(i).getAtomicMass());
    }


    System.out.println(getGrams(moles, mass));

    for(Elements e : list){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

and finally the Elements enum

```
package com.example.justin.firstapp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.math.*;


public enum Elements {

/* SYMBOL NAME ATOMIC_WEIGHT ELECTRONEGATIVITY */
H("Hydrogen", 1.00794f, 2.1f), He("Helium", 4.0026f, 0), Li("Lithium",
        6.941f, 0.98f), Be("Beryllium", 9.01218f, 1.57f), B("Boron",
        10.811f, 2.04f), C("Carbon", 12.011f, 2.55f), N("Nitrogen",
        14.0067f, 3.04f), O("Oxygen", 15.9994f, 3.44f), F("Fluorine",
        18.9984f, 3.98f), Ne("Neon", 20.1797f, 0), Na("Sodium", 22.98977f,
        0.93f), Mg("Magnesium", 24.305f, 1.31f), Al("Aluminum", 26.98154f,
        1.61f), Si("Silicon", 28.0855f, 1.9f), P("Phosphorus", 30.97376f,
        2.19f), S("Sulfur", 32.066f, 2.58f), Cl("Chlorine", 35.4527f, 3.16f), Ar(
        "Argon", 39.948f, 0), K("Potassium", 39.0983f, 0.82f), Ca(
        "Calcium", 40.078f, 1), Sc("Scandium", 44.9559f, 1.36f), Ti(
        "Titanium", 47.88f, 1.54f), V("Vanadium", 50.9415f, 1.63f), Cr(
        "Chromium", 51.996f, 1.66f), Mn("Manganese", 54.938f, 1.55f), Fe(
        "Iron", 55.847f, 1.83f), Co("Cobalt", 58.9332f, 1.88f), Ni(
        "Nickel", 58.6934f, 1.91f), Cu("Copper", 63.546f, 1.9f), Zn("Zinc",
        65.39f, 1.65f), Ga("Gallium", 69.723f, 1.81f), Ge("Germanium",
        72.61f, 2.01f), As("Arsenic", 74.9216f, 2.18f), Se("Selenium",
        78.96f, 2.55f), Br("Bromine", 79.904f, 2.96f), Kr("Krypton", 83.8f,
        0), Rb("Rubidium", 85.4678f, 0.82f), Sr("Strontium", 87.62f, 0.95f), Y(
        "Yttrium", 88.9059f, 1.22f), Zr("Zirconium", 91.224f, 1.33f), Nb(
        "Niobium", 92.9064f, 1.6f), Mo("Molybdenum", 95.94f, 2.16f), Tc(
        "Technetium", 98, 1.9f), Ru("Ruthenium", 101.07f, 2.2f), Rh(
        "Rhodium", 102.9055f, 2.28f), Pd("Palladium", 106.42f, 2.2f), Ag(
        "Silver", 107.868f, 1.93f), Cd("Cadmium", 112.41f, 1.69f), In(
        "Indium", 114.82f, 1.78f), Sn("Tin", 118.71f, 1.96f), Sb(
        "Antimony", 121.757f, 2.05f), Te("Tellurium", 127.6f, 2.1f), I(
        "Iodine", 126.9045f, 2.66f), Xe("Xenon", 131.29f, 2.6f), Cs(
        "Cesium", 132.9054f, 0.79f), Ba("Barium", 137.33f, 0.89f), La(
        "Lanthanum", 138.9055f, 1.1f), Ce("Cerium", 140.12f, 1.12f), Pr(
        "Praseodymium", 140.9077f, 1.13f), Nd("Neodymium", 144.24f, 1.14f), Pm(
        "Promethium", 145, 1.13f), Sm("Samarium", 150.36f, 1.17f), Eu(
        "Europium", 151.965f, 1.2f), Gd("Gadolinium", 157.25f, 1.2f), Tb(
        "Terbium", 158.9253f, 1.1f), Dy("Dysprosium", 162.5f, 1.22f), Ho(
        "Holmium", 164.9303f, 1.23f), Er("Erbium", 167.26f, 1.24f), Tm(
        "Thulium", 168.9342f, 1.25f), Yb("Ytterbium", 173.04f, 1.1f), Lu(
        "Lutetium", 174.967f, 1.27f), Hf("Hafnium", 178.49f, 1.3f), Ta(
        "Tantalum", 180.9479f, 1.5f), W("Tungsten", 183.85f, 2.36f), Re(
        "Rhenium", 186.207f, 1.9f), Os("Osmium", 190.2f, 2.2f), Ir(
        "Iridium", 192.22f, 2.2f), Pt("Platinum", 195.08f, 2.28f), Au(
        "Gold", 196.9665f, 2.54f), Hg("Mercury", 200.59f, 2), Tl(
        "Thallium", 204.383f, 2.04f), Pb("Lead", 207.2f, 2.33f), Bi(
        "Bismuth", 208.9804f, 2.02f), Po("Polonium", 209, 2), At(
        "Astatine", 210, 2.2f), Rn("Radon", 222, 0), Fr("Francium", 223,
        0.7f), Ra("Radium", 226.0254f, 0.89f), Ac("Actinium", 227, 1.1f), Th(
        "Thorium", 232.0381f, 1.3f), Pa("Protactinium", 231.0359f, 1.5f), U(
        "Uranium", 238.029f, 1.38f), Np("Neptunium", 237.0482f, 1.36f), Pu(
        "Plutonium", 244, 1.28f), Am("Americium", 243, 1.3f), Cm("Curium",
        247, 1.3f), Bk("Berkelium", 247, 1.3f), Cf("Californium", 251, 1.3f), Es(
        "Einsteinium", 252, 1.3f), Fm("Fermium", 257, 1.3f), Md(
        "Mendelevium", 258, 1.3f), No("Nobelium", 259, 1.3f), Lr(
        "Lawrencium", 262, 0), Rf("Rutherfordium", 261, 0), Db("Dubnium",
        262, 0), Sg("Seaborgium", 263, 0), Bh("Bohrium", 262, 0), Hs(
        "Hassium", 265, 0), Mt("Meitnerium", 266, 0), Uun("ununnilium",
        269, 0), Uuu("unununium", 272, 0), Uub("ununbium", 277, 0);

static final class Holder {
    /** Maps the atomic number to the Elements */
    static final Map<Integer, Elements> map_atomicNumber = new HashMap<Integer, Elements>();
    /** Maps the symbol to the Elements */
    static final Map<String, Elements> map_symbol = new HashMap<String, Elements>();
}


private Elements(String fullName, float atomicMass, float electroNegativity) {

    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.atomicMass = new BigDecimal(atomicMass);
    this.electroNegativity = new BigDecimal(electroNegativity);

    Elements.Holder.map_atomicNumber.put(this.getAtomicNumber(), this);
    Elements.Holder.map_symbol.put(this.name(), this);
}

private final String fullName;
private final BigDecimal atomicMass;
private final BigDecimal electroNegativity;


public int getAtomicNumber() {
    return this.ordinal() + 1;
}


public String getSymbol() {
    return this.name();
}


public String getFullName() {
    return this.fullName;
}


public BigDecimal getAtomicMass() {
    return this.atomicMass;
}


public BigDecimal getElectroNegativity() {
    return this.electroNegativity;
}


public String toString() {
    return name() + "[fullName=\"" + this.fullName + "\", atomicMass=\""
            + this.atomicMass + "\", electroNegativity=\""
            + this.electroNegativity + "\"]";
}


public static Elements getByAtomicNumber(int atomicNumber) {
    return Elements.Holder.map_atomicNumber.get(atomicNumber);
}


public static Elements getBySymbol(String symbol) {
    return Elements.Holder.map_symbol.get(symbol);
}


public static String getSymbolByAtomicNumber(int atomicNumber) {

    Elements e = Elements.Holder.map_atomicNumber.get(atomicNumber);
    if (e != null)
        return e.getSymbol();
    else
        return null;
}


public static int getAtomicNumberBySymbol(String symbol) {

    Elements e = Elements.Holder.map_atomicNumber.get(symbol);
    if (e != null)
        return e.getAtomicNumber();
    else
        return 0;
}


public static boolean exists(String symbol) {
    if (null != Elements.Holder.map_symbol.get(symbol))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public static boolean exists(int atomicNumber) {
    if (Elements.Holder.map_symbol.get(atomicNumber) != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public static String toCorrectSymbol(String symbol) {

    String correct_symbol = "";

    correct_symbol += Character.toUpperCase(symbol.charAt(0));

    if (symbol.length() == 2) {
        correct_symbol += Character.toLowerCase(symbol.charAt(1));

    } else if (symbol.length() == 3) {
        correct_symbol += Character.toLowerCase(symbol.charAt(1));
        correct_symbol += Character.toLowerCase(symbol.charAt(2));
    }

    return correct_symbol;
}
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you turning the `getText()` into `String`? Have you tried turning it into `getText().toString()`? Try it out and let me know what's the result.

Comment: It maybe that you are receiving an `empty` String and not a null. You should check those too. I recommend using the `TextUtils.isEmpty()` when checking for empty `TextView`s or `EditText`s.

Comment: @McAwesomville I am. You gotta scroll all the way to the right. Unless you're talking about the one where its just the getText and not the crazy long line of code. If that's what you're talking about, that line works as is, it's the other one that is causing problems

Comment: I see. Okay. Have you also tried putting in Logs? Try adding one in your `getMoles()` before returning a value. See if it's actually returning one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe getText() on a blank EditText will never return null - it will return an empty string.  So your first check if both fields are non-null is *always* executing, and since the grams are an empty string, that's what gets put in the TextView.  Try checking the length of the EditText instead like

```
if (!(editTextGrams.getText().length() == 0) && !(editTextMoles.getText().length() == 0)) {
```

I think this will fix your problem.  Also watch out for your computations when getting grams from moles and vice versa, it looks like the case where you're getting grams from moles is using editTextGrams.getText() to compute the grams but you've already established that the field is blank - you should be using editTextMoles in that case.  Basically, I think you just have variables flip-flopped in the two else/if cases.

Comment: thanks I was messing with it and saw that mistake with the computations. Now the moles to grams works but the grams to moles force closes the app and for some reason debugging won't run so back to searching for errors it is